# How to prove these two properties?

Tags: probability, statistics

For two independent r.v. $X\sim N(\mu_1, \sigma^2)$ and $Y\sim N(\mu_2, \sigma^2)$. Show that
$$
P(\max\{X^2, Y^2\}>c)\le \alpha.
$$

Comment: To be sure, are you defining quantile here as an upper area quantile, i.e. $P(W>\chi^2_1(\alpha))=\alpha$ for $W\sim \chi^2_1$?

Comment: @Golden_Ratio Yes, just the normal definition.

Comment: @Golden_Ratio https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile_function

Comment: @Bob I wouldn't call that the "normal" definition; it is typically the inverse CDF value, i.e. corresponding to the *lower* tail area, including in the wiki link you shared

Comment: @quasAliki Can you double check the statement? Are $\mu_1,\mu_2$ arbitrary? Because if $\mu_1,\mu_2$ are large in absolute value, I don't see how you can bound that probability.

Comment: @quasAliki Your latest comment is $\mu_1\mu_2=0$. Do you mean each $\mu_i$ should be zero?

Comment: @quasAliki It's just the probability as a function of the mean of $X$. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume $\chi_1^2(\alpha)$ is the quantile of a $\chi^2_1$ distribution corresponding to upper tail area $\alpha$, i.e. $P(W>\chi_1^2(\alpha))=\alpha$ for $W\sim \chi^2_1.$

Note that $\mu_1\mu_2=0$ implies at least one of $\mu_1,\mu_2$ is zero. WLOG, assume $\mu_2=0,$ so $Y^2\sim \chi^2_1.$ Then

$$P\left(\min\{X^2,Y^2\}>\chi^2_1(\alpha)\right)=P\left(X^2>\chi^2_1(\alpha),Y^2>\chi^2_1(\alpha)\right)\\
\underbrace{=}_{\text{indep}}\underbrace{P\left(X^2>\chi^2_1(\alpha)\right)}_{\leq 1}\underbrace{P\left(Y^2>\chi^2_1(\alpha)\right)}_{=\alpha}\leq \alpha.$$

Note that $X^2$ is [non-central chi squared](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncentral_chi-squared_distribution) with one degree of freedom and noncentrality parameter $\mu_1^2.$ This should help you with the second part where they want you to consider the probability as a function of $\mu_1$.

---

Note: As you have correctly noted in the comments, in this case, you can can use the fact that for $c\geq 0,$
$$P(X^2>c)=P(|X|>\sqrt c)\\=P(X>\sqrt c)+P(X<-\sqrt c)\\=P(X-\mu_1>\sqrt c-\mu_1)+P(X-\mu_1<-\sqrt c-\mu_1)\\=1-\Phi(\sqrt c-\mu_1)+\Phi(-\sqrt c-\mu_1),$$
where $\Phi$ is the CDF of a standard normal.

Comment: Thanks for the first part, I got it. But I am confused about the second part. I try to discuss it. If $X^2>Y^2$, then $f(x)=P(Y^2>\chi_1^2(0.05))=0.05$ because $Y^2$ is chi-square. But if $X^2<Y^2$, what is $f(x)=P(X^2>\chi_1^2(0.05))$? It is not a chi-squre.

Comment: You can't take individual cases $X^2>Y^2$ (or vice versa) in evaluating the probability because these are random variables; you can't control their values. But please look again at my first part solution; it actually gives you the basic expression for the second second part. Further simplification of that expression would use the fact that $X^2$ is **noncentral** chi squared, for which I gave you the link.

Comment: If you wanted to take individual cases they way you did, you'd have to use conditional probabilities to properly account for the fact that $X^2\gtrless Y^2$ is itself a random event :$P(\min\{X^2,Y^2\}>r)=P(X^2>r|Y^2>X^2)P(Y^2>X^2)+P(Y^2>r|Y^2\leq X^2)P(Y^2\leq X^2),$ but I don't see how that's simpler to evaluate.

Comment: @quasAliki great point! yea, looking into the noncentral chi square distribution is probably overkill in this case. I've updated my answer with your suggestion

Comment: Now, $f(\mu_1)=1-\Phi(\sqrt c-\mu_1)+\Phi(-\sqrt c-\mu_1)$. Can we plot it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133264/discussion-between-golden-ratio-and-quas-aliki).